# Plus.Momentsapi.write returns ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}

Tags: android, google-plus

Pounding the keyboard for a few days without resolution on this.

```
Plus.PlusOptions plusOptions = new Plus.PlusOptions.Builder()
            .addActivityTypes("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity")
            .build();
    mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext, this, this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addApi(Plus.API,plusOptions)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
            .build();
```

....

```
if (mGoogleClient.isConnected()) {

                ItemScope itemScope = new ItemScope.Builder()
                        .setType("http://schema.org/Thing")
                        .setUrl(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.web_url))
                        .build();
                Moment moment = new Moment.Builder()
                        .setType("http://schema.org/AddAction")
                        .setTarget(itemScope)
                        .build();
                Plus.MomentsApi.write(mGoogleClient, moment).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        Log.d("Settings", status.toString());
                    }
                });
```

D/Settings﹕ Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}

I've checked the Developer Console for completeness, and I do have the google+ api enabled.

Achievements, high scores, and interactive posts in the same code all work. It just refuses to to moments.